# How to Trace JAR file execution is hosted on IIS6.0 Server

Tags: administration, iis, web-services

We are using few JAR files in our web-application hosted on IIS6.0 Server and those files are used in somepages, we want to trace the execution of those files (both in client and server side) however tools like httpwatch...are not helping us in this. Do we have any specific tool to trace the execution of the JAR files in IIS Environment

This post may not be related to this community, thanks for your patience.

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't appear to have anything to do with SharePoint. You may want to consider posting this on stack overflow.

Having said that, [check out Fiddler](http://www.fiddlertool.com/fiddler/version.asp). It is a great HTTP tracer / debugger.

Comment: Agreed, and you shouldn't be sent back here if your question is even vaguely related to SharePoint, as there a lot of people knowledgeable with SharePoint also on StackOverflow.